# formatting sql date using php date function

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to print a table containing formatted dates drawn from a MySQL database.  I have this:

```
echo ' . date("D\, F d", $row['date2']) . ';
```

The result is formatted correctly, but it returns Thursday, January 1, 1970 instead of the date contained in the SQL table.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely getting a date string back. `date()` takes a unix timestamp. Use `strtotime` to convert it first

```
echo date("D\, F d", strtotime($row['date2']));
```